# How to hide the navigation bar or replace it by my own bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios5, xcode4.2

I use the navigation controllers because it handle the transition movement which is nice to see in any app. However, the navigation controllers add a default navigation bar which is, in many cases, not useful for me since i have my own specifications and my own bars models.
My question is, is there any way to keep the Navigation controller (their movement) and in the same time, change the default bars by something else.

Thanx for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you have figured this out by now, but in case you haven't.  The answer is "YES".  If you want to remove the navigation toolbar completely, then all you have to do is put

```
self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

in your viewDidLoad method.  However, if you want the toolbar to show on some views and not on others, you should put that code in your viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Just realized I had setToolbarHidden and not setNavigationBarHidden.  Corrected my answer